# Must all domains be on the SSL certificate when canonicalizing domains via 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, mod-rewrite

I have a few domains all pointing to the same server. Only one of those domains (the main one) is actually on my SSL certificate. I've included the following in my `httpd.conf` file for some time so they all permanently redirect to a single domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

The intention is all domains MUST 301 redirect to `www.example.com` as HTTPS.  However, I have recently noticed these redirects are occurring - but as a 302 redirect. I tried a sanity check [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=251abc1e-9a5c-52c5-8c39-6930d484a7e6) and it seems to work as I expect it should.

**So to recap:**

What happens: `http://sub1.example.com` results in a 302 redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

What should happen: `http://sub1.example.com` results in a 301 redirect to `https://www.example.com`.

My question is, must all domains be listed on the SSL certificate in order for such a redirect to occur as a 301?  I'm just pulling at straws here.

Just for completeness, here are the request/response headers of the initial page and destination page when this occurs.

**Request header for the initial page (`sub1.example.com`):**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: sub1.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Response header for the initial page (`sub1.example.com`):**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 21:05:16 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.example.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=1
Expires: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 21:05:18 GMT
Content-Length: 212
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=150
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**Request header for the destination page (`www.example.com`):**

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: <redacted>
```

**Response header for the destination page (`www.example.com`):**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Oct 2017 21:05:16 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=150
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: @MrWhite Why did you edit my question?  As far as I can tell, you didn't change anything, you just replaced random parts with the exact same thing.   Is this a back-handed attempt at increasing your rep?  Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'd really rather not open a meta question on this.

Comment: The intention of the edit was to improve readability. I didn't replace anything. I changed the _formatting_ of the URLs/hostnames and unlinked the example URLs. URLs, domains, filesystem paths and filenames are generally easier to read when formatted as _inline code_, rather than _plain text_. You had formatted the first hostname as inline code, but left the remaining 8 as plain text, which meant the URLs also got auto-linked by the editor. I didn't get any rep increase (you don't get rep for edits once you have 2000 rep). If you find the edit that offensive then you can simply roll it back.

Comment: @MrWhite No, that's fine.  It seems the diff on SO doesn't show the formatting changes you mentioned, so it appeared to be frivolous changes.  The diff marked some other parts as changed such as "I've", but I'm sure it's just the diff incorrectly thinking it was changed.  Just trying to keep the community strong by preventing people from potentially gaming the system, which it seems you are not.  Thanks for the correction and I'll try to remember to mark filesystem paths and filenames as inline code along with fake URLs/hostnames to prevent them from auto-linking going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing a 302 redirect then it would seem that "something else" is ultimately triggering that redirect. The code you've posted, if it is executed, is clearly a 301.

> must all domains be listed on the SSL certificate in order for such a redirect to occur as a 301?

No, providing you are only redirecting *from* HTTP - as your examples seem to show.

If your other domains were not listed on the SSL cert then you would obviously get problems trying to redirect from `https://otherdomain.com/...`, since the request would never reach your server (unless the user accepted the invalid cert).

Comment: I can confirm you are correct in that "something else" is ultimately triggering the 302 redirect.  I commented out the rewrite code and the 302 still happened.  I'll have to figure out what is causing this now, Thanks.